# fail to start gradle project with spring

Tags: java, spring, gradle, spring-tool-suite, new-project

I've installed Gradle plugin on Spring Tools Suite.

When I start gradle spring project, the project is not getting created and I get below exception :

```js
org.gradle.tooling.GradleConnectionException: Could not install Gradle distribution from 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.5.1-bin.zip'.
 at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DistributionFactory$ZippedDistribution.getToolingImplementationClasspath(DistributionFactory.java:137)
 at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.loader.CachingToolingImplementationLoader.create(CachingToolingImplementationLoader.java:40)
 at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.loader.SynchronizedToolingImplementationLoader.create(SynchronizedToolingImplementationLoader.java:43)
 at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.LazyConsumerActionExecutor.onStartAction(LazyConsumerActionExecutor.java:101)
 at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.LazyConsumerActionExecutor.run(LazyConsumerActionExecutor.java:83)
 at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.CancellableConsumerActionExecutor.run(CancellableConsumerActionExecutor.java:45)
 at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.ProgressLoggingConsumerActionExecorg.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
 at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.BlockingResultHandler.getResult(BlockingResultHandler.java:46)
 at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DefaultModelBuilder.get(DefaultModelBuilder.java:50)
 at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DefaultProjectConnection.getModel(DefaultProjectConnection.java:41)
 at org.eclipse.buildship.core.workspace.internal.ConnectionAwareLauncherProxy.newModelBuilder(ConnectionAwareLauncherProxy.java:64)
 at org.eclipse.buildship.core.workspace.internal.DefaultModelProvider.fetchModel(DefaultModelProvider.java:68)
 at org.eclipse.buildship.core.workspace.internal.DefaultModelProvider.supportsCompositeBuilds(DefaultModelProvider.java:165)
 at org.eclipse.buildship.core.workspace.internal.DefaultModelProvider.fetchModels(DefaultModelProvider.java:75)
 at org.eclipse.buildship.core.workspace.internal.DefaultModelProvider.fetchEclipseGradleProjects(DefaultModelProvider.java:99)
 at org.eclipse.buildship.core.workspace.internal.SynchronizeGradleBuildsJob.fetchEclipseProjects(SynchronizeGradleBuildsJob.java:91)
 at org.eclipse.buildship.core.workspace.internal.SynchronizeGradleBuildsJob.synchronizeBuild(SynchronizeGradleBuildsJob.java:81)
 at org.eclipse.buildship.core.workspace.internal.SynchronizeGradleBuildsJob.runToolingApiJob(SynchronizeGradleBuildsJob.java:73)
 at org.eclipse.buildship.core.util.progress.ToolingApiJob$1.run(ToolingApiJob.java:73)
 at org.eclipse.buildship.core.util.progress.ToolingApiInvoker.invoke(ToolingApiInvoker.java:62)
 at org.eclipse.buildship.core.util.progress.ToolingApiJob.run(ToolingApiJob.java:70)
 at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:56)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
 at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
 at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(Unknown Source)
```

Maven project starts without any problem.

My configuration is - Windows 7 (64 bits) STS(32 bits) JRE 1.8 (32bits)

Comment: please specify more details, show your build.gradle file

Comment: Thank you Daniel, I Updated my Question.

Answer (score 0):

A quite common question, please refer to this for a solution:

http://nodsw.com/blog/leeland/2006/12/06-no-more-unable-find-valid-certification-path-requested-target